# ERROR: Inserting EQUALOP

Tags: sml, ml

Hi can someone help me figure why i get the

```
ERROR: Inserting EQUALOP
```

for the following code?

```
fun generator inchan outchan n = if n>0                         
           then 
               (let 
                   fun loop () =                          
                         val c = recv(outchan)
                         val _ = send (inchan, c)
                in  
                   (loop ();(generator inchan outchan (n-1)))
                end)
            else inchan;
```

Answer (score 3):

You enter a `let` statement, and then define a function. However, inside that function, you
seem to want to define more variables. To do this, you need another `let` statement. Without it, you will get a syntax error like this.

Try using this instead:

```
fun loop () = send (inchan, recv (outchan))
```

Or, if you want the separate lines for more clarity:

```
fun loop () =
    let
      val c = recv (outchan)
    in
      send (inchan, c)
    end
```

Or maybe

```
fun loop () = 
    let
      val c = recv (outchan)
      val _ = send (inchan, c)
    in
      ()
    end
```

Comment: Using this generator code how do i recursively create new mailboxes such that the outchan of the first is the inchan of the next?

Comment: I have no idea what it is you're trying to do, because you haven't explained it. This code is a replacement for your loop function, and nothing else. If another part of the code isn't working, you should ask another question.

Comment: I have to implement a generating function that will generate a stream of mailboxes.  The generating function will be parameterized by two channels, the in and out channels for the first mailbox, and integer dictating how many mailboxes to generate.  This function should be recursive and allocate new channels.  On the recursive invocation of generator the previous out channel should be the in channel for the next mailbox. A new channel should be allocated as the new out channel. I have written a code of the generator function but i think theres an infinite loop because it doesnt stop.

Comment: The code for the generating function is 

`
 
 fun generator inchan outchan n =

                 let

             fun loop incha outcha num =

                   if (n>0)

                      then ((mailbox incha outcha) ; (loop outcha (channel()) (n-1)))

                   else (inchan)

            in (loop inchan outchan n)
    end;

`